# Fuelphp oil generate scaffolding with field: primary key not null auto-increment

Tags: php, mysql, fuelphp

Is there a way to generate a field in fuel php that is an INT, that's also a primary key, not null, auto increment?

In the documentation it looks like:

```
php oil g scaffold <modelname> [<fieldname1>:<type1> |<fieldname2>:<type2> |..]
```

If I try something like:

```
oil g scaffold test testid:int primary key not null auto_increment
```

I get an error message of "undefined offset"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID gets generated automatically by oil scaffold so you don't have to type that. And after running the migration it will be created in the table as a primary key. 
If you want to change the migration after the scaffold is generated you can edit the migration file (fuel/app/migrations/..).

If you have for example

```
 oil g scaffold test field:string field2:string
```

The migration will look something like this

```
namespace Fuel\Migrations;

class Create_tests
{
public function up()
{
    \DBUtil::create_table('tests', array(
        'id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' => true),
        'field' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'field2' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'created_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int'),
        'updated_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int'),

    ), array('id'));
}

public function down()
{
    \DBUtil::drop_table('tests');
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that explains a lot. Thank you!

Comment: So if I changed my mind about a field in the model, can I just edit the model file and migrate it with oil?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that since the migration will move up so I think you need to create a new migration to modify something as you can see in the documentation you have options to create migration for example when you want to rename a field (oil generate migration rename_field_name_to_username_in_accounts). If you look at the docs about oil you have a lot of options like this.